# GA4 Manually track / override platform

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, gtag.js, google-analytics-4

We are currently updating our Hybrid Web app to Google Analytics 4 and would like to track the platform using gtag (not by integrating firebase tracking into cordova). However, on all platforms the App seems to only track the platform `web`. Is there any way to override this?

I have found through https://ga-dev-tools.google/ga4/dimensions-metrics-explorer/ that the corresponding dimension should be `platform`. However neither tracking an event with that parameter, nor setting it directly seem to have the desired effect:

```js
gtag('set', { platform: 'Android' });
gtag('event', 'page_view', { platform: 'Android' });
```

They both get send as event parameters and show up in the individual events, but the platform tracked in both cases stays `web`.

Answer (score 0):

You can override Google Analytics 4 Fields (i.e. with Server-Side GTM) however it seems that not all fields in the Event Data object can be edited.

Here you can find a list of verified ones: https://www.simoahava.com/gtm-tips/override-ga4-fields-in-server-side-gtm/

Is present for example `client_hints.platform` (Client Hints API. Platform name., i.e. macOS). I don't know if that's what you're interested in.

Comment: Thanks! I did see `client_hints.platform` and immediately dismissed it as "That's probably just the user agent". But haven't tried it yet for some reason. Will do next week and see if that gets picked up